# Prove that the functions cos3x, sin3x, cos4x, sin4x are linearly independent in ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

i tries to solve using the Wronskian test  for independence, but the answer is weird please help 
Prove that the functions cos3x, sin3x, cos4x, sin4x are linearly independent.

Comment: Not only are they linearly independent, they are orthogonal wrt an inner product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Hilbert_space_interpretation

Answer (score 3):

If $a\cos 3x+b\sin 3x+c\cos 4x+d\sin 4x=0$ for all $x$, the case $x=0$ gives $a+c=0$ while $x=\pi$ gives $c-a=0$, so $a=c=0$. The case $x=\pi/2$ gives $-b=0$ so $b=0$, while the case $x=\pi/3$ gives $d\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}=0$ so $d=0$.